# bash replacing text in string with wildcard sed/ regnex

Tags: bash, sed, regular-expression

I am wondering if this is possible,
I want to mass replace a text in various files, this is not a problem.
What i cannot figure out, or even if its possible is to replace the text in a specific manner.

For example:

```
String = XXXXX_name($var1);
```

XXXX is fixed, so XXXX replace with YYYY for example, simple enough. but the more complicated part is:

```
($var1);
```

I want to insert another variable, so the match would be `");"` <-- insert before this, BUT if the string is already had two variables `($var1,$var2);` to not insert anything.

Now to add another thing in, Var1 and Var2 can be called various things, so the match would have to be `if $ > 1` inside `()` then to do nothing, `If $ = 1 inside ()` then to insert `", $var2"` before `);`

String = `XXXXX_name($var1);`
Should become:
String = `YYYYY_name($var1, var2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$ echo 'String = XXXXX_name($var1); ' | 
    sed -E -e 's/XXXXX_name\((\$[[:alnum:]_]+)\);/YYYYY_name\(\1, \$var2\);/'
String = YYYYY_name($var1, $var2);
```

In extended regular expressions, the unquoted parenthesis capture the part within them and sed's `\1` puts the captured part back in the replacement part.

Comment: Just put this through a few tests and this could actually work, does exactly as i hoped. This will save me many hours of searching and replacing :) Thank you sir

Comment: How would you do this the other way a around as well if you dont mind me asking? 
If you where to insert the variable at the start of the the open bracket?
Its okay, i see its switching the end replace around: 
    sed -E -e 's/mssql_\((\$[[:alnum:]_]+)\);/sqlsrv_query\(\$var2\, \1);/'

Comment: @DaveHamilton, mmh, I'm not sure what you mean. `\(` matches the literal left parentheses, `(...)` captures the insides (to `\1` in the replacement part), `\$` matches a literal dollar sign, and `[[:alnum:]_]` any number of alphanumerics or underscores. And `\)` matches the right paren. So, edit those as necessary.

Comment: ah, yes, it doesn't matter _where_ in the replacement part you drop the `\1`.

Comment: is there anything special with this expression as when i pass the -i parameter over to attempt to replace the content in a file, it doesn't replace anything?

Comment: @DaveHamilton you;re probably using BSD sed instead of GNU sed. Both support `-i`, but BSD sed requires `-i'.bak'` or similar to provide a backup file name.

Comment: the FreeBSD sed takes `-i extension`, i.e. `-i .bak` (or `-i ""` for no suffix), while the GNU and OpenBSD ones take `-i[extension]`, i.e. `-i.bak` (or just `-i` for no suffix). Not sure what could cause it to not replace anything, unless you have the FreeBSD version and did, `sed -i -E -e ...`, which, if I understood right, would make `-E` the extension and sed would use basic instead of extended regex, and nothing would likely match.